# Could someone please help me understand why the normal forces are acting downward here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

[image]
The question said that 'the floor of the lift exerts forces of magnitude 678N and 452N respectively on Albert and Bella'. This is the normal reaction force. But why are they taken as downwards? Shouldn't they be upwards? Doesn't the force on the person by the lift always act upwards?

Comment: It's written in the big, double rectangle: Draw a diagram showing the forces **acting an** [sic] **the LIFT only**. The normal forces on both persons point upwards, not on the lift floor.

Comment: Oh yeahh. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you :) but it still doesn't make sense because the question said that the lift **exerted** the forces and since these are the normal forces, they shouldn't be acting on the lift and they shouldn't be downwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram shows the forces on the **lift**.

> the **floor of the lift** exerts **(upward)** forces of magnitude 678N and 452N respectively on **Albert and Bella**

These two upwards forces on Albert and Bella accelerate them upwards.

Applying Newton’s third law.

**Albert and Bella** exerts **downward** forces of magnitude 678N and 452N respectively on **the floor of the lift**

**Update** as a result of a comment

Here are the free body diagrams for the lift and its passengers.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that makes sense but I don't think that that's right because the downward force that they both exert would be their weight and the upward force is the normal reaction force and the normal ≠ weight. And in the next parts their masses were calculated
Albert's was 60 kg and Bella's was 40 kg. So their weights are 588N and 392N, meaning that they're exerting that much amount of force on the lift. 
So how can we say that they both exert the same amount of force on the lift?

Comment: @Ah_well On Albert there are two forces. The upward force on Albert due to the floor of the lift and the downward force on Albert due to the gravitational attraction of the Earth.  If the lift (and Albert and Bella) are accelerating upwards then the force on Albert due to the lift is larger than the downward gravitational attraction. This means that there is a net force upwards on Albert which causes Albert to accelerate upwards $F=ma$.  The same is true of Bella.

Comment: Yes so the force is upwards but here in order to find the acceleration we are taking it as downwards. Why is that? The normal forces (678 and 452) should be upwards!
Also sorry if I'm being a pain and thank you for trying to help me out :)

Comment: @Ah_well Do not worry. You calculatio shows the lift to be moving with an upward acceleration of $1.5\, \rm m\, s^{-2}$ and this must also be the acceleration of the passengers.  Again from your solution you will note the up arrow in brackets $(\uparrow)$ which is used to define to positive direction.

Comment: Yes I know that. My only problem is why are the forces: 678N and 452N acting downwards when they clearly should be upwards?

Comment: @Ah_well Those forces act downwards on the lift because the passengers are "hindering" the acceleration of the lift and those forces act upwards on the passengers as you will see for the addition to my answer.

Comment: Ohhh I got it and I'm so happy. I just wasn't able to grasp how Newton's third law could apply here but you've made it clear. God bless you! Thank you so sooo much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the normal force is supposed to be in upward direction. The solution of the acceleration is the resultant tension force(upward) and total mass that it carries(mass of two people and lift) divided by the total mass.